# Importing .cer certificate from cmd

Tags: certificate, certutil, certreq

Importing a `.cer` certificate with `certutil` utility can't manage to match it with its private key although the certificate signing request was created on the same machine.

I'm using `certreq` to generate the `.csr` file used for getting this certificate and in the `.inf` I have the `Exportable = True` flag.
Doing the import manually through the mmc wizard works, but not when running the following command from the admin console.

`certutil -addstore -f "My" "website_aps_production.cer"`

Moreover after importing the certificate with certutil, looking in mmc I noticed the Friendly Name is reset (appears as None).

I already tried the repairstore mechanism after importing the certificate from cmd, but did not help.

`certutil -repairstore my >cert_thumbprint<`

**UPDATE**

I tried importing the certificate using `certreq -accept -machine website_aps_production.cer`, but this is throwing an error: *A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority. 0x800b010a* and there is an additional warning in the console *A certificate issued by the certification authority cannot be installed. Contact your administrator.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I managed to automate the certificate import process using PowerShell.

```
Set-Location -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My

Import-Certificate -Filepath "C:\website_aps_production.cer"
```

This way, the certificate is imported in the local computer's store and matched with its corresponding private key which can be further exported.

A more convenient solution is, however, creating everything using openSSL and not using the certificate store at all. This way the privatekey is exported independently from the certificate.

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout pvkey.key -out csr.csr -subj "/C=test/ST=test/L=test/O=test/OU=test/CN=test" -config "C:\openssl.cnf"
```